# Find initial value exponential decay

Tags: exponential-function

You have a heat of 76 after 4 hours and the heat decays exponentially with time towards the outside which is 0 degrees.

The heat decays by a rate of 4.1 degrees per hour.

Find the initial value

So I tried something like this

A(4) = 76 = A0e^(4.1*4)

And then I solve A0 by dividing both sides with e^(4.1*4)

But that gives a unreasonable answer. Any help here?

Comment: When does the heat decay by a rate of 4.1 degrees per hour?

Answer (score 1):

Exponential decay to zero must
take  the form ...
$$f(t) = A e^{-kt} $$
for some positive $k$, so...
$$f'(t) = -kA e^{-kt} $$
The information you are given tells you that ...

$$f(4) =76 \text{   and   }f'(4)=-4.1 $$
You need to solve for $A$, can you take it from there?

******************* EDIT  **************************

First solve for $k$
$$ \frac{f'(4)} {f(4)}  =\frac{-4.1} {76}   = -k  $$
Then use that value of $k$ to solve for $A$
$$A = 76\;e^{4k} $$

Comment: I still don't get it, something isn't making sense in my head.
So i make k = 4.1 and then solve it?
Or do i find k?

Comment: See my edit for more details